# Function declared outside class scope but not friend. How does this work?

Tags: c++, function, friend

I have the following class:

```
class PhoneCall{
private:
    string number;
public:
    /*some code here */
};
```

Now, I have declared a function (not *friend* to *PhoneCall*) which does some specific operation and returns a *PhoneCall* object

```
PhoneCall callOperation()
```

Another which takes a *PhoneCall* object as parameter

```
void userCall(PhoneCall obj)
```

I was expecting it not to work unless it is explicity declared as a friend to that class.

Why and how do these functions work even when they are not *friend* to the *PhoneCall* class ?

> A friend function of a class is defined outside that class' scope but
>   it has the right to access all private and protected members of the
>   class
>   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_friend_functions.htm

Comment: In your opinion: which private or protected member of PhoneCall does `userCall()`  requires?

Comment: If instead of `PhoneCall` you were to declare those function with the `std::string` type, would you need the functions to be friends with `std::string`?

Comment: `A friend function of a class is defined outside that class' scope but it has the right to access all private and protected members of the class`. It doesn't say a non-friend function can't return or take as parameter an object of that class.

Comment: as declared in the prototype , `userCall()` access the member `string number` via setter @fukanchik

Comment: @AbrarShariarGalib Oh, really? And which part of this prototype declares this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass, manipulate and return instances of a class without beeing its friend, as long as you do not access its **private or protected members**.

According to *N4296. p. 261*:

> **11.3 Friends**
>
> A friend of a class is a function or class that is given permission to
> use the private and protected member names from the class.

Unless you declare your move or copy **constructors** as private or protected, the object can be also copied or moved as a whole.

So practically a `private` `PhoneCall` constructor will prevent non-friends from instantiating `PhoneCall` objects:

For example:

```
class PhoneCall{
    private: PhoneCall(){}
};
```

This prevents non-friend code from instantiating the class:

```
PhoneCall callOperation(){
    return PhoneCall();
}
```

will results in a compile-time error:

```
error: 'PhoneCall::PhoneCall()' is private
```

---

*Edit: Added info on private constructors following M.M`s suggestion in the comments.*

Comment: Maybe OP is overlooking the point that it is the **member names** which may not be used inside the non-friend code.  The object may still be copied as a whole, or have those members accessed in other ways which don't involve the name appearing.

Comment: @M.M Thanks for pointing this out. I just added a sentence about constructors.